# Select column names with X highest values

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have created a matrix of users and interactions with product categories, my data looks like this, where each row is a user and each column is a category, with the number indicating how many interactions they have made with that category:

```
    User     Cat1     Cat2     Cat3     Cat4     Cat5     ...
    1        0        1        0        2        30
    2        0        0        10       5        0
    3        0        5        0        0        0
    4        2        0        20       2        0
    5        0        40       0        0        0
    ...
```

I'd like to add a column (either in this query or in a fresh query on this table) which returns, for each user, the 3 column names that contain the highest values.

My complete data has 200+ columns.

Any suggestions on how I could achieve this in StandardSQL?

Here is the code I used to build my grid:

```
SELECT
  customDimension.value AS UserID,
  SUM(IF(LOWER(hits_product.productbrand) LIKE "Brand 1",1,0)) AS brand_1,
  SUM(IF(LOWER(hits_product.productbrand) LIKE "Brand 2",1,0)) AS brand_2,
  SUM(IF(LOWER(hits_product.productbrand) LIKE "Brand 3",1,0)) AS brand_3,

FROM
  `table*` AS t
CROSS JOIN
  UNNEST (hits) AS hits
CROSS JOIN
  UNNEST(t.customdimensions) AS customDimension
CROSS JOIN
  UNNEST(hits.product) AS hits_product
WHERE
  parse_DATE('%y%m%d',
    _table_suffix) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 day)
  AND DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 day)
  AND customDimension.index = 2
  AND hits.eventInfo.eventCategory = 'Ecommerce'
  AND hits.eventInfo.eventAction = 'Purchase'
GROUP BY
  UserID
  LIMIT 50
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Your schema is very poor and you are going to find this to be a difficult problem to solve because of it. Unpivot your schema to look like `User | Category | Count` where a user is repeated many times for each distinct category, and the problem becomes MUCH easier to solve.

Comment: Thank you @JNevill - is it possible to transform my current table into this format?

Comment: @BenP I've written it out a bit in the answer below. Basically you want to "Unpivot" your data. It looks like there is a built in `unpivot` transform in bigquery that will help with this, but I've also included the traditional SQL way of performing an unpivot as well. If you have a lot of records to unpivot, this step may take some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL (and has no dependency on number of category columns - even though example has just 5)

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *, 
  ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY(
    SELECT SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(0)]
    FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(TO_JSON_STRING(t), r'[{"}]', ''))) kv
    WHERE LOWER(SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(0)]) <> 'user'
    ORDER BY CAST(SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(1)] AS INT64) DESC
    LIMIT 3
  ), ',') top3_cat
FROM `yourproject.yourdataset.yourtable` t
```

You can test, play with above using dummy data from your question:

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 user, 0 cat1, 1 cat2, 0 cat3, 2 cat4, 30 cat5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 0, 0, 10, 5, 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 2, 0, 20, 2, 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 0, 40, 0, 0, 0 
)
SELECT *, 
  ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY(
    SELECT SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(0)]
    FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(TO_JSON_STRING(t), r'[{"}]', ''))) kv
    WHERE LOWER(SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(0)]) <> 'user'
    ORDER BY CAST(SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(1)] AS INT64) DESC
    LIMIT 3
  ), ',') top3_cat
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
```

with result

```
Row user    cat1    cat2    cat3    cat4    cat5    top3_cat     
1   1       0       1       0       2       30      cat5,cat4,cat2   
2   2       0       0       10      5       0       cat3,cat4,cat2   
3   3       0       5       0       0       0       cat2,cat3,cat1   
4   4       2       0       20      2       0       cat3,cat4,cat1   
5   5       0       40      0       0       0       cat2,cat3,cat1
```

> I've updated my question with the code I used to build the matrix, would you mind showing how I would integrate your solution?

```
#standardSQL
WITH `query_result` AS (
  SELECT
    customDimension.value AS UserID,
    SUM(IF(LOWER(hits_product.productbrand) LIKE "Brand 1",1,0)) AS brand_1,
    SUM(IF(LOWER(hits_product.productbrand) LIKE "Brand 2",1,0)) AS brand_2,
    SUM(IF(LOWER(hits_product.productbrand) LIKE "Brand 3",1,0)) AS brand_3,
    ...
    ...
  FROM
    `table*` AS t
  CROSS JOIN
    UNNEST (hits) AS hits
  CROSS JOIN
    UNNEST(t.customdimensions) AS customDimension
  CROSS JOIN
    UNNEST(hits.product) AS hits_product
  WHERE
    parse_DATE('%y%m%d',
      _table_suffix) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 day)
    AND DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 day)
    AND customDimension.index = 2
    AND hits.eventInfo.eventCategory = 'Ecommerce'
    AND hits.eventInfo.eventAction = 'Purchase'
  GROUP BY
    UserID
    LIMIT 50    
)
SELECT *, 
  ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY(
    SELECT SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(0)]
    FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(TO_JSON_STRING(t), r'[{"}]', ''))) kv
    WHERE LOWER(SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(0)]) <> LOWER('UserID')
    ORDER BY CAST(SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(1)] AS INT64) DESC
    LIMIT 3
  ), ',') top3_cat
FROM `query_result` t
```

Comment: Thanks Mikhail, could you please explain this query? Is the query name `project.dataset.table` arbitrary or should this be an actual table name? DO I have to move my initial query into the WITH section?

Comment: WITH \'project.dataset.table' is there just for you to test , play with query. For your real stuff  - you should remove  with part and use your real table name instead of project.dataset.table - will update answer in a sec to be more clear

Comment: if you data comes not from table but rather from query  - you should simply put this query inside WITH

Comment: I've updated my question with the code I used to build the matrix, would you mind showing how I would integrate your solution?

Comment: Thanks again, I have it working but some of my user identifiers start with numbers and are being included in the top 3 - how could I exclude them?

Comment: Please clarify. I would expect eliminating user column in WHERE clause with <> 'user' so replace with your user column name. Make sense?

Comment: As of using result of query vs. table - just include your query inside WITH statement replacing dummy data. I will update the answer as looks like you still confused here - sorry if I am wrong

Comment: Perfect, got it, thank you for your patience and detailed explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment: If your data were in a more reasonable format like `user | category | cat_count` you could run something like:

```
SELECT user, group_concat(category) as top_3_cat
FROM
    (
        SELECT user, category, rank() OVER (PARTITION BY user ORDER BY cat_count) as cat_rank
        FROM yourtable
    ) cat_ranking
WHERE cat_rank <= 3;
```

Doing this in your current schema would be nearly impossible given the number of categories you have as columns.

I would focus on unpivoting your table first so it can be ran through the sql above. This may be possible using [bigquery's `unpivot` transform](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Unpivot-Transform_57344656) although I'm not sure what the limit is for unpivotting columns.

```
unpivot col:cat1, cat2, cat3, cat4, cat5, catN groupEvery:N
```

I don't use bigquery, so I'm not certain how that gets applied to your dataset, but it looks promising.

The other option is UNION many statements together to make up `yourtable` in that sql above:

```
SELECT user, 'cat1' as category, cat1 FROM yourtable
UNION ALL SELECT user, 'cat2', cat2 FROM yourtable
UNION ALL SELECT user, 'cat3', cat3 FROM yourtable
UNION ALL SELECT user, 'cat4', cat4 FROM yourtable
UNION ALL SELECT user, 'cat5', cat5 FROM yourtable
UNION ALL SELECT user, 'catN', catN FROM yourtable;
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use arrays in bigquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select array_agg(s.colname order by s.val desc limit 3)
        from unnest(array[struct('col1' as colname), col1 as val),
                          struct('col2' as colname), col2 as val),
                          . . .
                         ]
                   ) s
       ) as top3
from t
```